# P2P multiplayer android NAT traversal solutions/libraries?

Tags: android, p2p, multiplayer, hole-punching, nat-traversal

I'm writing a multiplayer android game, in which the reliability of connection between peers doesn't matter, as the only multiplayer aspect of it is informative (each group of players get the same puzzle ad the P2P connections are used to inform each player of the others' progress each 5 seconds),
I can use a matchmaking service like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/features/multiplayer/matchmaking/peer-to-peer) to communicate the ips of the matched group, but I've no idea where to go from there,I only kow that i can not establish direct connections between players behind NATs,I found some solutions but they were all costly or restrictive (for example photon),
so my question is What are the available NAT traversal solutions/libraries that can be used for multiplayer android game development for free?

Comment: The general idea is to get a publicly-facing server, and bounce messages between clients through that server. That way, everybody in the game dials "out"; no-one has to dial "in" to a client.

Comment: @greeble31 unfortunately I can't afford that right now (zero budget) , and I don't think free options like gcp f1.micro compute can handle a large number of clients, so I wanted to use it as a fall back mechanism for clients unreachable by the NAT traversal methods.

Comment: Depending on your target audience you could try ipv6 connections, which don't suffer from NAT. But deployment differs between countries and providers.